# Django: Include a html on ajax request

Tags: django, ajax

I am using Django as my Webframework togehter with Ajax for async calls.
When a button is pressed I want an entire HTML file to be loaded in (like normal includes).
This is the AJAX code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{% url 'project-detail' project_object.id %}",
    type: 'get',
    data: {
        ...
    },    
    success: function (response) {
        $("#div1").html("{% include 'projects/recommendations.html' %}")
    }
})
```

As you can see I try to wrap `{% include 'projects/recommendations.html' %}` with ".". This unfortunatley doesnt work.

As a work around I thought of reading the file in and output the string.

As the to be included file is also relatively large ~150 LOC I try to avoid having it all in one file.

Is there a way to neatly load this in?

Comment: How about returning ```{% include 'projects/recommendations.html' %}``` as response in your success callback function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suggest you using backtick

```
$("#div1").html(`{% include 'projects/recommendations.html' %}`)
```